# WordPress JavaScript doesn't execute unless I paste it in the console

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am developing a WordPress website using Oxygen Builder. I have custom user registration form that I made with Forminator.

There's a section where the user needs to select at least 3 options and I need to validate that before they click the next button to go to the next section of the form.

I am using this JavaScript code which is being included in the site in the footer, but it does not work. However, if I paste it into the browser's console, then it works. What could be the issue?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

var checked = 0;

jQuery('#forminator-custom-form-83--page-1 input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    
    if(jQuery(this).is(':checked')){
        checked++;
    }
    
    if(checked < 3){
        jQuery('button.forminator-button-next').attr("disabled","");
    } else {
        jQuery('button.forminator-button-next').removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    
    
});
```

});

Comment: Is the form from Forminator in the source code, or added later via JavaScript? Is the form in an iframe?

Comment: @Caleb The form is added via JavaScript, it's not an iframe

Comment: Then you'll need to contact support for the form generator, and ask how you can know when the form has loaded. This is hopefully an event that's triggered that you can hook onto.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that your form is being generated dynamically after page ready. Try using `jQuery(window).load(function() {....})` instead of `jQuery(document).ready(function() {})`.

Also try placing the snippet in the end in `footer.php` after all scripts.

Comment: I've tried to change the document.ready to window.load but it still doesn't work

Comment: It could be then that the form loads even later, try adding a delay of like 10 seconds to this code and see if it works. If it does it means you need to find a form load trigger which might be available in the current form or you can write one yourself.